# How to use Stripe Elements provider as a client component in NextJs 13?

Tags: typescript, stripe-payments, next.js13

I was trying to implement Stripe payments in my NextJs 13 app. While trying to wrap my form in the Elements provider, I am getting a "use client" related error.

I am new to NextJs and typescript, so pardon me if I am missing some basics here.

Below is my code as well as the error page.

```js
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js"
import { Inconsolata, Mukta } from "next/font/google"
import SubscriptionModal from "./components/modals/SubscriptionModal"
import Navbar from "./components/navbar/Navbar"
import "./globals.css"
import ToastProvider from "./providers/ToastProvider"

import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js"

const stripePromise = loadStripe(
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY!
)
const inconsolata = Inconsolata({ subsets: ["latin"] })
const mukta = Mukta({ weight: "500", subsets: ["latin"] })

export const metadata = {
  title: "Subscription App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inconsolata.className}>
        <header className={mukta.className}>
          <Navbar />
        </header>
        <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
          <SubscriptionModal />
        </Elements>
        <ToastProvider />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

[NextJs error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVrtY.png)

To get rid of the error, I tried creating a Stripe provider by wrapping the Elements in "use client" directive, as suggested.

layout.tsx file

```js
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js"
import { Inconsolata, Mukta } from "next/font/google"
import StripeProvider from "../app/providers/StripeProvider"
import SubscriptionModal from "./components/modals/SubscriptionModal"
import Navbar from "./components/navbar/Navbar"
import "./globals.css"
import ToastProvider from "./providers/ToastProvider"

import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js"

const stripePromise = loadStripe(
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY!
)
const inconsolata = Inconsolata({ subsets: ["latin"] })
const mukta = Mukta({ weight: "500", subsets: ["latin"] })

export const metadata = {
  title: "Subscription App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inconsolata.className}>
        <header className={mukta.className}>
          <Navbar />
        </header>
        <StripeProvider stripePromise={stripePromise}>
          <SubscriptionModal />
        </StripeProvider>
        <ToastProvider />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

StripeProvider.tsx file

```js
"use client"

import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js"
import Stripe from "stripe"

interface StripeProviderProps {
  stripePromise: Stripe | null | PromiseLike<Stripe | null>
}

const StripeProvider: React.FC<StripeProviderProps> = ({ stripePromise }) => {
  return <Elements stripe={stripePromise} />
}

export default StripeProvider
```

However, this did not solve the issue.
In the StripeProvider.tsx file, the stripe prop of Elements component is returning a type error like below:

> Type 'import("stripe").Stripe | PromiseLike<import("stripe").Stripe | null> | null' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/dexter-ubuntu/webdev/next-prjs/next-13-prjs/subscription-app/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/types/stripe-js/stripe").Stripe | PromiseLike<import("/home/dexter-ubuntu/webdev/next-prjs/next-13-prjs/subscription-app/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/types/stripe-js/stripe").Stripe | null> | null'.
> Type 'Stripe' is not assignable to type 'Stripe | PromiseLike<Stripe | null> | null'.ts(2322)
> react-stripe.d.ts(666, 5): The expected type comes from property 'stripe' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ElementsProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'

I think correct type has not been described for stripePromise object. The type I have currently declared (Stripe | null | Promise<Stripe | null>) is from Stripe documentation for React.
[Stripe for React](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react)

Any help is appreciated. Much Thanks!!

Edit1: To address RyanM's comments, I went through the [dev.to](https://dev.to/stripe/type-safe-payments-with-next-js-typescript-and-stripe-4jo7) link and found one difference with my code i.e. the use of await keyword for loadStripe.

```
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';

const stripe = await loadStripe(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY!);
```

But I could not try out the same because of layout.tsx not being asynchronous in nature.

Edit2: I have checked commenting out the Elements provider and then the app runs fine. Still, for the ease of reproducing the error, I am sharing my repo link. [Github repo](https://github.com/Avinash104/subscription-app)

Comment: There are a lot of things going on even in the initial app.  Can you try a stripped down version that just returns a simple Stripe interface, like the Payment Element(https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-element) and making sure that works.  Additionally I would recommend logging the Stripe publishable key just to be sure (many times this is a root issue).

Comment: You might also want to review this guide: https://dev.to/stripe/type-safe-payments-with-next-js-typescript-and-stripe-4jo7

Comment: Hi @RyanM, what do you mean by logging my public stripe key? If you meant I should re-check it, I did that but to no avail.